# Free iPhoto Alternative

Tags: macos, open-source, software-rec, iphoto

I'm looking for a free iPhoto alternative for OS X. I reinstalled my Mac, and lost the original iLife cd. So instead of trying to find it somewhere, I'd like to use an Open Source alternative instead.

Nice to have:
  * iPhoto library importer
  * Facebook exporter
  * Exporter for other online photo apps

I'm NOT looking for a pure online-based service. I want something for my desktop that acts as a good replacement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Picasa](http://picasa.google.com/mac/).

It works with your iPhoto library and there is a [plugin](http://apps.facebook.com/picasauploader/) for Facebook export. Not sure about exporting to other online photo apps though.

Comment: Will Picasa work without having to push everything online? Or is the online part only an add-on?

Comment: @Evert: The online part is indeed an add-on. It's called "Picasa Web Albums".